# Mysql: Insert values to gaps in sequence

Tags: php, mysql

So my question is this: What is the best way to check what rows are missing from 1 - 14 and then to `INSERT` my new value into the open row.

I know that it is not necessary to fill the gaps in your database, but I am doing a course in php and I need to achieve the following:

I have a table with `primary key` set to `id`, but not `auto_increment`. So if one of the 14 values get deleted the new value needs to be placed in the gaps.

I have read up a little bit and found a few question on SO, but they all just want to check if the gaps exist, I somehow need to tell it what and where it is allowed to update the values.

I have this

```
SELECT MIN(t1.position_id)+1 AS unused
    FROM playerposition AS t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM playerposition AS t2 WHERE t2.position_id = t1.position_id+1)
    UNION
    -- Special case for missing the first row
    SELECT 1
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM playerposition WHERE position_id = 1)
) AS subquery
```

But that only returns the first row and I don't really understand the query. Any help, advice or guidance would be appreciated.

UPDATE

I have made a change to the query and I now get the empty values. My new query looks like this

```
SELECT a AS id, b AS next_id, (b - a) -1 AS missing_inbetween
FROM
  (
    SELECT a1.position_id AS a, MIN(a2.position_id) AS b
    FROM playerposition  AS a1
      LEFT JOIN playerposition AS a2 ON a2.position_id > a1.position_id
    WHERE a1.position_id <= 14
    GROUP BY a1.position_id
  ) AS tab

WHERE
  b > a + 1
```

I still need help with the `INSERT` part though

Comment: If you are doing a course in php, you are maybe tasked to do this in php (e.g. use a loop). The values 1-14 sound very specific. Are you tasked to fill every missing value (like your 2nd query looks like)? Or just one (like your first query and your explanation imply)? What shall happen in case all values from 1 to 14 already exist? So I would recheck your task, maybe you missed something. Generally: you can insert values from a select simply by `insert into tablename (column1, ...) select your-select-query-with-the-right-amount-of-columns-to-fit-the-columnname-list-from-the-insert`

Comment: No I don't need to fill every value. If a new value is posted I need to check the table to see if there is a gap from 1 - 14, if one is found then I insert the value into that gap, if not then just echo out something. If value 2 was deleted I need to replace the value with the same PK of 2

Comment: Well, in that case, your first query with an additional `select min(unused) from (` at the beginning should do the job (you have to add a condition to be <=14, but that I'll leave to you). You can add `insert into playerposition (position_id) select ...`, but then you cannot easily echo out if all values are filled. Still not sure if that is your actual task, but that is up to you to decide.

Comment: Can I ask what the best way is to do this, if this was not a course would you suggest I use php or learn how to do it in mysql? And thank you very much for the help, I will tackle both options and see what works best for me.

Comment: Well, as you already mentioned in the beginning: "I know that it is not necessary to fill the gaps in your database". So the best way to do this is probably: you do not care (well, actually, you would even want to make sure you would never reuse a primary key again, so you would not even want to do it). And just to clairfy: if you get stuck again with the code, you can of course ask again, that was no "we won't help you anymore", but a "you can probably do it on your own from here". You can also add your final solution as an answer, for others that might have a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I got this working, just working on the <=14, but will post an answer as soon as I have that working. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code helped me to achieve the result I wanted. I am sure that improvements can be made to make the code better

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultCheckPos) == 14) {
        echo "You can only have 14 positions in total";
    } else {
        $testQ = "SELECT min(unused) AS unused
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(t1.position_id)+1 AS unused
    FROM playerposition AS t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM playerposition AS t2 WHERE t2.position_id = t1.position_id+1)
    UNION
    -- Special case for missing the first row
    SELECT 1
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM playerposition WHERE position_id = 1)
) AS subquery";

        $resultTest = $conn->query($testQ);
        $rowTest = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTest);
        $row = $rowTest['unused'];

        $insertTest = "INSERT INTO playerposition (position_id, position_descr) VALUES ('$row','$posDesc')";
        $resultInsertTest = $conn->query($insertTest);
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
```